# Django - SMTPSenderRefused when sending email from contact form

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, gmail

I've made a page that is supposed to send an email to the `to_email` when the submit button is clicked inside of a form.  I disabled captchas using [this link](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) as I was advised in [this video playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhzasigpf3Q) that I've been following for tutorials but for some reason, I'm getting an authentication error. I found an answer to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153804/smtpsenderrefused-at-submit-contact-form-5-5-1-authentication-required) but it involved using the string version of the `HOST_password` in the `settings.py` file, which I am already doing. The emails and passwords that I am using are correct, so what could be causing the problem?

Below is the traceback log from the page:

```
Django Version: 1.8.6
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'artist_tracker')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/students/test/bandsync/src/bandsync-repo/artist_tracker/views.py" in contact
  58.       send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently =False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in send_mail
  62.     return mail.send()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  303.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  107.                 sent = self._send(message)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in _send
  123.             self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in sendmail
  731.             raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)

Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused at /contact/
Exception Value: (530, '5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 l85sm10088128qhl.3 - gsmtp', u'webmaster@localhost')
```

Comment: I really hope that's not your real email and password that you've stored in the git repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django- \[Errno 111\] Connection refused when using smtp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950585/django-errno-111-connection-refused-when-using-smtp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have misspelled one of your settings. You have:

```
EMAIL_HOSTS_USER = '<your email>'
```

It should be:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<your email>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try app specific passwords if you have 2 step authentication turned on. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34713901)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).